# mutiscreen in one page flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

i have one in gridview. and when the item is clicked it will display a different layout based on the data sent. so every data sent has a different appearance.
Is there any reference that can help me solve this problem?

Comment: Have you read about [Navigation and Routing in Flutter](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/navigation)? Could you provide a copy of your code and be more specific about where you are having an issue?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.